# Probability puzzle app: Correlation coefficient question, Uniform distribution, Cannot get the write answer.

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

Suppose mathematical and writing ability are independent — and therefore uncorrelated — in the general population.

To keep things tractable, imagine math and writing ability are independently uniformly distributed on the interval [0, 1], and that students attend college if and only if the sum of their mathematical and writing abilities is larger than one.

Each point below is a simulated person; the color indicates whether they attend college. Among the population of college students, what is the correlation between writing and math ability?

### My approach so far

I really do not get what I am doing wrong?

$Corr\left( x,y\right) = \dfrac {cov\left( xy\right) }{\sigma _{x}\sigma _{y}} $

So then I try and calcuate $cov\left( xy\right) = E\left( XY\right) -E\left( X\right) E\left( Y\right)$

$E(XY) = \int ^{1}_{0}\int ^{1}_{1-y}xydxdy = \dfrac {5}{24}$

I do a similar process and calculate $E\left( X\right) =  E\left( Y\right) = \dfrac {1}{3}$

So that my final answer is $Corr\left( x,y\right)$ = $\dfrac {7}{10}$

But apparently this is not correct?

Comment: I don't understand the vote for closing this question.

Comment: @drhab:  Did you have difficulty seeing where "the color indicates whether they attend college"?  There could be an interesting math problem here, and the OP may have gotten to a place where Readers can address a difficulty, but the presentation doesn't fully credit that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PDF $f(x,y)$ of $(X,Y)$ under condition $X+Y>1$ is constant on area $\{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2\mid x+y>1\}$ and takes value $0$ outside this area.

Let's say that it takes value $c$ on $\{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2\mid x+y>1\}$.

Then we find:$$1=\int\int f(x,y)dxdy=\frac12c$$
So that implies that $f(x,y)=c=2$ on area $\{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2\mid x+y>1\}$ (and you wrongly did it with $f(x,y)=1$ there).

Now try again.

Comment: I am not sure really where you got 1/2c from?, I can see it should be double as it is half the total area

Comment: Do you agree that $\iint_Acdxdy=\frac12c$ if $A$ denotes the triangle $\{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2\mid x+y>1\}$?

Comment: Ok yes, this is a very simple problem, but illustrates a good point for me, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

$E(X)=E(Y)=\frac23$ – the population of college students has a mean above average, not below average.

The problem is that you're just integrating the quantity over the region but not normalizing by the integral of the density over the region, which is $\frac12$.

Comment: Ok, yes that makes sense. Now I get -1/2

Comment: @user567309: Yes, a negative value makes sense.

Comment: @user567309 The better their mathematical ability the less are the conditions posed on their writing ability. No a negative correlation.

Comment: @drhab: I think you meant "So"? :-)

Comment: @joriki Ah, yes. Just to late to repair. Btw, nice to see you back. I missed you for some time.

Comment: @drhab: Thanks :-) I'm not sure yet how long I'm here to stay, but for now it's fun :-)